# Derivation of the Temperature Dependence of the Boltzmann Distribution

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, quantum-chemistry, statistical-mechanics

In lecture notes, Atkin's *Physical Chemistry*, etc. the Boltzmann Distribution is derived by first claiming that the system takes on properties of its weightiest configuration. The weight is therefore maximised, utilising Lagrange multipliers.

\begin{align}
\nabla \ln{W} - \alpha \ \nabla \sum_i n_i - \beta \ \nabla \sum_i n_i\epsilon_i &= 0
\\
\to \frac{\partial{\ln{W}}}{\partial{n_i}} - \alpha - \beta \epsilon_i &= 0
\end{align}

The Stirling Approximation transforms the derivative to something we can work with, and the Boltzmann distribution is eventually derived.

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \ln{W}}{\partial n_i} &= -\ln{\frac{n_i}{N}} \\
&\vdots \\
\frac{n_i}{N} &= \frac{e^{-\beta\epsilon_i}}{\displaystyle \sum_i e^{-\beta\epsilon_i}} \hfill
\end{align}

The derivation is left there with no mention of the value of $\beta$, though it is later claimed $\beta = \frac{1}{kT}$. How is the value of $\beta$ ascertained?

Comment: Isn't that the _definition_ of temperature?

Comment: Hardly an expert on this, but afaik you can derive $\beta = 1/kT$ if you define $S = k\ln W$, but I've also seen some cases where one defines $\beta = 1/kT$ and derives $S = k\ln W$ from it. I guess either way it is a postulate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relationship between $\beta$ and $T$ comes from experimental observations like $E=\frac{3}{2}RT$, i.e. if you add $E$ amount of energy to a mole of monatomic gas, then you raise the temperature by $\frac{3}{2}R$ degrees.

$E = N_A\langle \varepsilon \rangle = N_A \sum_i p_i \varepsilon_i =  \frac{N_A}{q} \sum_i \varepsilon_i e^{-\beta\varepsilon_i}$

$\varepsilon_i e^{-\beta \varepsilon_i}  = - \frac{d }{d \beta} e^{-\beta \varepsilon_i} \to \langle \varepsilon \rangle = - \frac{1}{q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial\beta}$

$q = \left( \frac{2\pi m}{h^2\beta} \right)^\frac{3}{2}V \to E = \frac{3N_A}{2\beta} \to \beta = \frac{N_A}{RT} $

Comment: What OP cited is a derivation of the Boltzmann distribution starting from a micro-canonical ensemble (which has a fixed energy). Here, $\beta$ arises as a Lagrange multiplier, and one needs to relate it to the thermodynamic tenperature $T = 1/(\partial S / \partial E)$. On the other hand, you started from a partition function, which means you are working with a canonical ensemble that has a fixed temperature. In this case, you have $\beta=1/kT$ from the very beginning, and you don't need to compare against the internal energy of the monatomic ideal gas to derive what is already there.

Answer (score 4):

What OP cited is the derivation of the Boltzmann distribution starting from the micro-canonical ensemble, characterized by a fixed energy and a fixed number of constituent particles. In mathematical terms, the problem statement is as follows:

> Maximize the function $\ln W(\{n_i\})$ under the constraints $\sum_i n_i \epsilon_i = E$ and $\sum_i n_i = N$.

The solution is a function of $E$ and $N$, so let's define

> $\ln \Omega(E, N)$ := (constrained maximum of $\ln W$ as a function of $E$ and $N$),
>
> $\tilde{n}_i (E, N)$ := (value of $n_i$ at the constrained maximum).

Notice that $\ln\Omega = \ln W(\{\tilde{n}_i\})$. Also, this quantity is what appears in Boltzmann's entropy formula $S=k\ln\Omega$ because $\Omega$ is the number of available states for given values of $E$ and $N$. This observation enables us to relate $\ln\Omega$ to the thermodynamic temperature:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \ln \Omega}{\partial E} = \frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial S}{\partial E} = \frac{1}{kT}.
\end{equation}
Now, OP's question can be rephrased as follows:

> When deriving the Boltzmann distribution starting from the micro-canonical ensemble, $\beta$ is introduced as a Lagrange multiplier associated with the constraint $\sum_i n_i \epsilon_i = E$. How can we relate $\beta$ to the thermodynamic temperature, i.e., establish that $\beta = \frac{\partial \ln \Omega}{\partial E}$?

The underlying principle is really the chain rule in multivariate calculus:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial \ln \Omega}{\partial E} &= \sum_i \frac{\partial \ln W}{\partial n_i}\bigg|_{n_i = \tilde{n}_i} \frac{\partial \tilde{n}_i}{\partial E}\\
&= \sum_i (\alpha + \beta\epsilon_i)\frac{\partial \tilde{n}_i}{\partial E}\\
&=  \alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial E}\Big(\sum_i \tilde{n}_{i}\Big) + \beta\frac{\partial}{\partial E}\Big(\sum_i \tilde{n}_{i}\epsilon_i\Big)\\
&= \alpha \frac{\partial N}{\partial E} + \beta \frac{\partial E}{\partial E}\\
&= \beta.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: I'm not sure I follow where $\beta = \frac{\partial \ln{\Omega}}{\partial E}$ is coming from. Could you clarify that?

Comment: If you are talking about where I rephrased your question, the reason is that $\Omega (E, N)$ is what enters Boltzmann's relation $S = k \ln \Omega$, where $S$ is a function of $E$ and $N$. Then, one should have $\partial \ln\Omega /\partial E = k^{-1}\partial S / \partial E = 1/kT$.